# ParsleyJS custom validation is not working in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation, parsley.js

What I would like to achieve is writing a custom validator for Parsley to validate multiple email addresses entries in input.

#### Here is my HTML:

```
<input class="tags tags-email" type="hidden" value="" id="tags" data-validation-minlength="1" data-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-testmultiple/>
```

#### Here is my custom validator file:

```
window.ParsleyConfig = {
  validators: {
    testmultiple: {
      fn:function(value) {
      console.log("OK");
      var re = new RegExp(/^regexText);
      var val = value.val();
      var tagsArray = val.split(',');
      var lastTag = tagsArray[tagsArray.length -1];

      console.log('keyup OK');

      if(!re.test(lastTag)) {
        return  false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  },
  priority: 32
},
messages: {
  testmultiple: "This value can not contain dollar sign ($)."
}
```

};

#### Here is my controller where I am firing parsley:

```
function initUser() {
  $(".tags").select2({tags: frd.emailList, width: '100%'});
  $('form').parsley();
}
```

#### Here is my index.html file where I incule the file:

```
<script src="components/validation/bsa-validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bower_components/parsleyjs/dist/parsley.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am using AngularJS and my custom validator never fires. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `multiple`, it's already used by parsley.

Comment: Edit your question accordingly. Any errors in the console?

Comment: Edited. No errors in the console. When I debug in the developer tool I noticed it does not enter the function of custom validator.

Comment: You still have `data-multiple="3"` in your html. Your error message doesn't correspond

Answer (score 0):

I updated html like this: (input type is "hidden" ruins the logic)

```
<input class="tags" type="text" value="" id="tags" data-parsley-tagsemailvalidation="2" data-parsley-trigger="change"/>
```

I updated custom validator: (custom validator naming is important. Do not use camelCase. All names must be lowercase.)

```
window.ParsleyConfig = {
  validators: {
    tagsemailvalidation: {
    fn: function (value, requirement) {
    var re = new RegExp(/regexText/i);

    var returnValue = true;
    var tagsArray = value.split(',');

    //var lastTag = tagsArray[tagsArray.length -1];

    var index;
    for(index = 0; index < tagsArray.length; index++) {
      if(!re.test(tagsArray[index])) {
        returnValue = false;

        if(index == tagsArray.length - 1) {
          var tagsInput = $('.select2-search-field').prev();
          tagsInput.css('border', '1px solid red');
        }
      }
    }

    return returnValue;
  },

  priority: 32
}
},
 i18n: {
 en: {
  tagsemailvalidation: 'You have wrong email adresses. Please fix it'
 },
 tr: {
  tagsemailvalidation: 'Kırmızı olarak belirtilmiş eposta adresleri hatalı'
 }
}
};
```